# Pull smallest value

Tags: php, mysql

I know mysql has the MIN() function pulls out the smallest value located in a specific column.
I was wondering is there a way to pull out the smallest value for each corresponding id and exclude the values that equal 0?

For example, the 2 ids have multiple prices that were entered. I need to exclude '0', and then pull out the min for 1, and then the same for 2, etc etc.

```
id     price
=============
1       0
1       33.0
1       21.7
2       0
2       99.22
```

Comment: Doesn't adding `WHERE price != 0` solve this?

Comment: ID is not unique?? then how is it an `ID`?

Comment: @Neal: It could be a product id, but not the unique identifier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be something like

```
select id, min(price) from t where price > 0 group by id;
```

Comment: Haha, yep, right when I hit post I saw the orange alert box.  Oh well, good to have agreeing answers, eh?

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, min(price)
from table
where price > 0
group by id
```